# How can I set my environment variable in atom when executing commands

Tags: environment-variables, atom-editor

I am trying to set my environment variables to

> $env:DEBUG="*,-babel"

But I cant figure out where to use this setting in the Atom editor

Comment: You can use a config file for this usually.

Answer (score 1):

To make the shell's environment variables available to Atom, install following two small atom packages:

[env-from-shell](https://atom.io/packages/env-from-shell)

[auto-run](https://atom.io/packages/auto-run)

env-from-shell settings: enter comma delimited list of needed environment variables in it's settings panel.  Check off `auto-run` box.

auto-run settings: if not already present, enter `env-from-shell:copy` in it's settings panel.  A benefit of the `env-from-shell` package is no external configuration files have to be moved from directory to directory as projects change.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```js
process.env.DEBUG = "*,-babel"
```

in your (new) `$HOME/.atom/init.coffee` [init file](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/).

(Your directory may vary, see your `process.env.ATOM_HOME`.)