# A problem with Atom Editor while compiling C++ code

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I'm running Atom as IDE for C++ development on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). When I'm trying to compile it, i get this error:

'g++' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process.

How could I solve it? I've heard something about configuring a path, but I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: If you give the command `which g++` on a command prompt, what does it say?

Comment: It shows: /usr/bin/g++

Comment: Ok, good, then it's installed. Does `Atom` have environmental settings or toolchain settings? Does `g++` start if you do just run `g++` (it should say something like `g++: fatal error: no input files`)?

Comment: g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: This is what I've got typing g++ in terminal

Comment: I don't know if it has or not..

Comment: Ok, good. I'd then search for environmental settings in Atom. Perhaps it starts all subprocesses with a clean `PATH` unless you set it up somehow. You could also try specifying the full path to g++ in Atom but I think you'd have problems with other tools in that case (like the linker and pre-processor). Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246328/7582247) will help

Comment: I've installed them, but i'm struggling  with setting the PATH, I really don't know how to do it.